# Merge Maven Sonar reports

Tags: maven, sonarqube

I have a doubt about merging reports produced by Sonar. I have a multi-module project and due to its complexity i want to produce a Sonar report (not only a coverage report using jacoco) for each module. After that i would like to merge all the reports (maybe in the parent directory or even outside the project) to see all the statistics in an integrated Sonar report. Anyone can help me doing this integration?
I now that it is possible using Ant and Jacoco reports but i want more than coverage reports, that's why i need to merge Sonar and not only jacoco reports...

thanks in advance.

Tiago

Answer (score 1):

This is precisely the point of the (commercial) [Portfolio Management](http://www.sonarsource.com/products/plugins/governance/portfolio-management/) (Views) plugin. However I don't know of free (as in beer) alternatives.